# Jersey POST Requests and closing the InputStream

Tags: jersey, jax-rs, inputstream

when I have a method in Jersey that listens to a POST request, and when I have an InputStream as an argument in the method from which I want to get the data, do I need to close this InputStream or will Jersey handle this?

I haven't found any info on it. I had read RESTful Java with JAX-RS 2.0 a while back, and I don't remember if it was mentioned. Skimming through it now, I found several code examples, and the stream is not closed. I would think it's not necessary, but wanted to ask.

Comment: did you found the answer? I'm going to pass that inputStream as reference variable to EJB and close it there in try-finally block. What do you think?

Comment: @AzamatAlmukhametov I'd also like to know if you found an answer for this

Answer (score 0):

How do you get that InputStream reference? Through a MessageBodyReader? In that case if you are using a MessageBodyReader than you must not close the InputStream. There is even an explicit warning for this in the documentation.

[7.2.2.2. MessageBodyReader.readFrom](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/message-body-workers.html#d0e5658)

Anyway this link applies to Jersey v2. I don't know what's about version 1. Which version do you use?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. It's not in the MessageBodyReader, I already know not to close those or the output in MessageBodyWriter for that matter. It's the InputStream you get when doing a POST request. The method argument not annotated with something like `@QueryParam` or `@PathParam` is then the InputStream or the data that is sent to the server from the client.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question but the current answer does not answer the question for the case when not using the `MessageBodyReader`. For those who do wonder there are two other answers here on SO ([one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50672835/file-upload-endpoint-need-to-close-inputstream), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33083961/closing-jax-rs-client-response))

The short answer and summary is to call `close()` on the InputStream.

Background:

- one user debugged it and the stream is not automatically closed
- the `close()` method is idempotent so a 2nd call wouldn't hurt
- most of the users said to close() it or to use closeable with try-with-resources-statements