# Do I need try-finally for JAX-RS Response?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jax-rs

Do I have to use `try-finally` to ensure that JAX-RS `Response` is closed after getting the `Response`?

[Building and Invoking Requests | RESTfu­­l Jav­a­ wit­h ­JAX­-­­RS 2.­0­ (Second Edition)](https://dennis-xlc.gitbooks.io/restful-java-with-jax-rs-2-0-2rd-edition/en/part1/chapter8/building_and_invoking_requests.html)
 uses try..finally:

### Version 1

```
Response response = client.target("http://commerce.com/customers/123")
                          .accept("application/json")
                          .get();
try {
   if (response.getStatus() == 200) {
      response.bufferEntity();
      Customer customer = response.readEntity(Customer.class);
      Map rawJson = response.readEntity(Map.class);
   }
} finally {
  response.close();
}
```

I cannot use try-with-resource, as JAX-RS `Response` does not implement `AutoClosable`. So why do I have to use `try-finally`?

### Version 2 (without `try-finally`)

```
if (response.getStatus() == 200) {
      response.bufferEntity();
      Customer customer = response.readEntity(Customer.class);
      Map rawJson = response.readEntity(Map.class);
}
response.close();
```

### My Question is

The response is also **always** closed with Version 2, am I right?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33083961/closing-jax-rs-client-response: So if I use "response.bufferEntity()", then I NEED "try..catch". If I do not need "response.bufferEntity()" and call only "response.getEntity()", then I DO NOT NEED "try..catch", as resource is closed automatically after the first call of "response.getEntity()". Am I right?